# kenexa web service API

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

Has anyone integrated Kenexa Web service api in a sharepoint or .net site for recruting and talent managment purpose? I am going to do this for my new company and it looks like heavy xml configuration ..can anyone share their experience?

Their technology terminologies include 2x BrassRing, Talent Gateway etc..

It looks like their web service allows client site's UI to pass query parameters and connect to their database and search APIs and finally result in some search results.

Comment: I'd love to hear about this as I'm about to start a project that pulls data from Kenexa BrassRing and displays it on a website.

Answer (score 0):

The have some documentation here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21995062

I'm still trying to figure out how to enable CORS Headers for Cross-Origin requests so that we can query using AJAX directly from the user's browser, but it's nowhere to be found on the docs.